# How do I extend a list within a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

```
some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

becomes

```
some_list = [[1, 2, 10, 11], [3, 4, 10, 11], [5, 6, 10, 11]]
```

extending the individual lists (within a list) with a common list (in this case `[10, 11]`).

I want a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: edited my answer with new way, may be you like, *I am also a python learner*

Comment: That's similar to Volatility's comment in accepted answer.

Comment: I just use map, this is my first code using map()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehensions to the rescue!

```
some_list = [l + [10, 11] for l in some_list]
```

When you want to transform the elements in a list, a list comprehension is *usually* the answer.

Comment: Is there no way to do it without for loop? I was thinking of something like `some_list[:].extend([10,11])`. Of course it didn't work.

Comment: if you wanted to you could do `some_list = map(lambda x: x.extend([10, 11]), some_list)`, but the list comprehension is much easier (and readable)

Comment: That is precisely what Python Tutorial said xD

Comment: @elwc: You'd have to use an explicit for loop one way or another. The list comprehension is the most compact form you can find for this operation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters does my answer using `map()` makes some sense **?** , this is my fist code using `map()`. But   technically is my code same as yours?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, your code does the same thing; concatenate the extra list to each element in the list.

Answer (score 3):

```
some_list = [l + [10, 11] for l in some_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Map technique:**

```
>>> some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> some_list = map(lambda i : i + [10,11], some_list)
>>> some_list
[[1, 2, 10, 11], [3, 4, 10, 11], [5, 6, 10, 11]]
```

Other:

```
>>> some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> for i in some_list:
...     i.extend([10,11])
... 
>>> some_list
[[1, 2, 10, 11], [3, 4, 10, 11], [5, 6, 10, 11]]
```

Using slicing:

```
>>> some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> for i in some_list:
...     i[len(i):] = [10,11]
... 
>>> some_list
[[1, 2, 10, 11], [3, 4, 10, 11], [5, 6, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Running a method on each item in a container and getting results is rather easy with the following code:

```
class Apply(tuple):

    "Create a container that can run a method from its contents."

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        "Get a virtual method to map and apply to the contents."
        return self.__Method(self, name)

    class __Method:

        "Provide a virtual method that can be called on the array."

        def __init__(self, array, name):
            "Initialize the method with array and method name."
            self.__array = array
            self.__name = name

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            "Execute method on contents with provided arguments."
            name, error, buffer = self.__name, False, []
            for item in self.__array:
                attr = getattr(item, name)
                try:
                    data = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as problem:
                    error = problem
                else:
                    if not error:
                        buffer.append(data)
            if error:
                raise error
            return tuple(buffer)
```

In your case, you would want to write the following to extend each of the lists in your main container:

```
some_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
Apply(some_list).extend([10, 11])
print(some_list)
```